# Filtering by entity key name in Google App Engine on Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

On Google App Engine to query the data store with Python, one can use GQL or Entity.all() and then filter it. So for example these are equivalent

```
gql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE age >= 18"
db.GqlQuery(gql)
```

and

```
query = User.all()
query.filter("age >=", 18)
```

Now, it's also possible to query things by key name. I know that in GQL you do it like this

```
gql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE __key__ >= Key('User', 'abc')"
db.GqlQuery(gql)
```

But how would you now use filter to do the same?

```
query = User.all()
query.filter("__key__ >=", ?????)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.api.datastore import Key
query.filter("__key__ >=", Key.from_path('User', 'abc'))
```

Answer (score 3):

For me a similar way worked, while the "from_path" function did not worked in my case, this one did:

```
from google.appengine.api.datastore import Key

key = Key(your_string_with_key)
query.filter("__key__ = ", key)
```