# Filter query by key ID on Google App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine

I know there's a way to get a certain entity based on its key ID using `get_by_id(someId)`, but is there any way to get several entities with ID higher than some specified value? With a regular filter, we can do `query.filter("customId >", someId)`, but how can I do this for the built in key ID?

Comment: Duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544565/filtering-by-entity-key-name-in-google-app-engine-on-python

Comment: That's for key name. I'm asking about key ID. A key ID is an int value, where a key name is alphanumeric. Another question is, how did that guy from the linked question use >= operator on a key name?

Comment: @mohabithar - that's the same thing: key can be long or string.

Comment: If you're trying to get something like a "most recent customers" I think you'll be better off adding a "last_update" property and query on that.

Comment: Why do you want do this query? Because if you want filter objects created after the reffered id, the GAE IDs are not sequential between differents instances.

Comment: Are IDs not guaranteed to be in increasing chronological order? I know they're not sequential, such as 1, 2, 3, 4, but as long as new entities have greater IDs than existing entities, such as 1, 4, 6, 12, then that's all I need.

Comment: Please read the docs, as well as PeterKnego and Greg's answers CAREFULLY.  An ID can be either a string or a numeric value, and you can search by it.  You can do < and > comparisons on strings too.  However, there's no guarantees that the ID is always increasing.  You'd have to build your own ID generator for that.  Or use some other field that you can compare by. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Kinds_Keys_and_Identifiers

Comment: IDs are not guaranteed to be allocated in increasing order - in fact, you can more or less guarantee they won't be. Use a timestamp if you need to order by creation time.

Comment: @NickJohnson I believe you, but in what case would this not be true? I've created several entities, and while they're not sequential, the ID's are always increasing. What's the catch?

Comment: @mohabitar In production, IDs are allocated to servers in blocks; they then exhaust their block before requesting a new one. What ID you get depends on what server your request is handled by. In the dev_appserver, a single counter is used for all IDs, so they will appear increasing - but this is just the way the dev_appserver is implemented.

Comment: I'm being cheap with my write costs, so I thought by not creating an indexed timestamp or auto-incremeneting int field, I could save on indexed fields, and just use the system generated ID. So there's no other way then but to use an indexed property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the Key looks like a big meaningless string, it's actually a combination of your application ID, the type of entity and then either the numeric auto-assigned ID, or the you-generated key-name (parents and namespaces are in there too, but the same basic principles apply).

When you do a < or > comparison, or use 'order by' in a query, it's against these individual parts, rather than the string-encoding you see. So given that the app-ID and entity-type are the same, then you'll be comparing or sorting by the ID or key-name parts. The documentation explains it [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Queries_on_Keys).

In the filter method you can use '__key__' as the property name, and then construct a Key object (in python at least) using [Key.from_path](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_from_path)